# Surface poorly filled with sdl_ttf

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to make an openGL game in c++ and I'm trying to implement a text system,
to do this I'm trying to use SDL_ttf.

I already used SDL_ttf in an other project but with another api, so I made the same code but it happened to not fill the pixel data of the surface.

Here is my code :

```
void Text2Texture::setText(const char * text, size_t fontIndex){

    SDL_Color c = {255, 255, 0, 255};
    SDL_Surface * surface;

    surface = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(loadedFonts_[fontIndex], text, c);
    if(surface == nullptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error TTF_RenderText\n");
        return;
    }    

    GLenum texture_format;
    GLint colors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;

    if (colors == 4) {   // alpha
        if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGBA;
        else
        texture_format = GL_BGRA_EXT;
    } else {             // no alpha
        if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
        texture_format = GL_RGB;
        else
        texture_format = GL_BGR_EXT;
    }


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId_);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, colors, surface->w, surface->h, 0, texture_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);

    ///This line tell me pixel data is 8 bit witch isn't good ?
    std::cout << "pixel size : " << sizeof(surface->pixels) << std::endl;

    ///This line give me correct result
    fprintf(stderr, "texture size : %d %d\n", surface->w, surface->h);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

}
```

As you can see in the comment, the pointer pixels in surface have a size of 8 bit, witch is way too low for a texture. I don't know why It do that.

At the end, the texture data look to be fully filled with 0 (resulting with a black squad using very basic shaders).

In this project I'm using glfw to create an openGL context so I'm not using sdl and I did not initialized it.

However, I did initialize sdl_ttf, here is all I did before calling setText :

```
std::vector<TTF_Font *> Text2Texture::loadedFonts_;

void Text2Texture::init(){

    if(TTF_Init() == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "TTF_Init: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
    }

}

int Text2Texture::loadFont(std::string const& fontPath){

    loadedFonts_.emplace_back();

    loadedFonts_.back() = TTF_OpenFont(fontPath.data(), 32);

    if( loadedFonts_.back() == nullptr ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "TTF_OpenFont: %s \n", TTF_GetError());
        loadedFonts_.pop_back();
        return -1;
    }

    return ((int)loadedFonts_.size() - 1);

}

///The constructor initialize the texture :

Text2Texture::Text2Texture(){

    glGenTextures(1, &textureId_);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId_);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

}
```

My class got a static part here is it corp :

```
class Text2Texture {

public:

    Text2Texture();

    void setText(const char * text, size_t fontIndex = 0);

    unsigned int getId() const;

    //Partie static
    static void init();

    static void quit();

    static int loadFont(std::string const& fontPath);

private:

    unsigned int textureId_;

    //Partie static
    static std::vector<TTF_Font *> loadedFonts_;

};
```

I initialize sdl_ttf and load texture with static method then I create class instance to create specific texture.

If you find where is my mistake I would be pleased to read your answer.

(By the way, I'm not really sure using sdl_ttf is the good approach, if you have a better idea I would take it too but I would like to solve this problem first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format and type parameter of [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml)specifiy how one single pixel is encoded.
When the texture font is created, each pixel is encoded to a single byte. This means your texture consist of a single color channel and each pixel has 1 byte.
I'm very sure that `colors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel` is 1.
Note that it is sufficient to encode the glyph in one color channel, because the glyph consists of information that would fit in a single byte.

By default, OpenGL assumes that the start of each row of an image is aligned 4 bytes. This is because the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter by default is 4. Since the image has 1 (red) color channel, and is tightly packed, the start of a row is possibly misaligned.
Change the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter to 1, before specifying the two-dimensional texture image (`glTexImage2D`).

Since the texture has only one (red) color channel, the green and blue color will be 0 and the alpha channel will be 1 when the texture is looked up. But you can treat green, blue and even alpha channels to be read from the red color channel, too.
This can be achieved by setting the texture swizzle parameters `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G`, `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B` respectively `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_A`. See [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml).

Further, note that the texture parameter are stored in the texture object. `glTexParameter` changes the texture object which is currently bound to the specified target of the current texture unit. So it is sufficient to set the parameters once when the texture image is created.
In comparison, [`glPixelStore`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) changes global states an ma have to be set to its default value after specifying the texture image (if later calls to `glTexImage2D` rely on it).

The specification of the 2-dimensional texture image and setting the parameters may look as follows:

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, surface->w, surface->h, 0,
             GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G, GL_RED);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B, GL_RED);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_A, GL_RED);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```